# Mozzila Firefox "eat" html tags from Wordpress menu item title

Tags: html, wordpress, firefox

i have a problem with cross browser displaying of menu item title in WordPress menu.
I added this :

```
Name</br>Surname
```

for menu item title. Works perfectly in Chrome, Opera and IE.
Problem is Firefox - it shows all in same row.

After that i added

```
Name<span>Surname</span>
```

and in inspector, Chrome and Opera displays that tag, but Firefox not. Firefox displays only `Name Surname`.

Does anybody know anything about this?
I am doing this because in Mozilla text over-width my containers width and messing with other menu titles.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace first:

```
Name</br>Surname
```

with

```
Name<br>Surname
```

`</br>` tag is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

`</br>` is an invalid markup according to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/).

You are closing a `<br>` tag which has not started **and** should be self-contained.

You might want either `Name<br>Surname` or `Name<br />Surname`